# How are Grammar and Parts of Speech terms related?

Tags: grammar, linguistics, parts-of-speech

I'm wanting to build my understanding of English [grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar) and [parts of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech#English).

I want to sort out which terms build on each other but am getting confused because there are so many terms that I'm not seeing how they are related.

It seems like grammar is made of:

```
Clauses
Phrases
Words
```

And parts of speech is made of:

```
Noun
Pronoun
Adjective
Verb
Adverb
Preposition
Conjunction
Interjection
Article
```

But there are also terms like:

```
Subject
Object
Verb
```

That are found in the [Subject Verb Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object). Note: the term "Verb" appears twice in two categories that seem different. This is also confusing.

All terms are related to the structure of the English language, you know, like the title of this Stack Exchange. The terms fall broadly into three categories:

```
parts of speech
phrases
grammatical relations
```

I'm wanting to sort out the relation between these categories and thus the lists of English terms listed above.

For an example of what I'm looking to achieve:

The following words are all related to the structure of Atomic Physics and Chemistry; however, they don't make sense when they are all jumbled together:

```
water
electron
hydrogen
quark
neutron
proton
oxygen
```

However, by arranging them in a specific order they make more sense:

```
quark   electron    hydrogen    water
        neutron     oxygen
        proton
```

The key insight is: each of these words falls into categories. Each category provides the units required to build units in other categories.

It makes sense because quarks are the units that build electrons, neutrons, and protons; electrons, neutrons, and protons are the units that build atoms like hydrogen or oxygen; and atoms like hydrogen and oxygen build molecules like water.

**The question**

Can you explain the difference and relation between a) parts of speech (i.e. word categories), b) phrases (phrasal categories) and c) grammatical relations (like Subject or Object)?

I would especially appreciate some type of diagram that draws relations between the above three categories.

Comment: A part of speech is like a brick.  Grammar is like a house.

Comment: This is a good question and I do not think it is too broad. The question is really: Can you explain the difference between a)  parts of speech (i.e. word categories), b)  phrases (phrasal categories) and c)  grammatical relations (like Subject or Object). It's a good question for this site!

Comment: @sumelic there is literally one mention of one term that is connected to linguistics. In what way does that warrant reading an entire book on linguistics as opposed to asking a question on a question and answer site for the English language? The rest of the terms are either parts of speech, phrases, or grammatical relations. These terms are the fundamental units of the English language. I'm wondering how they are related. In what way is asking how terms are related too broad? It's a specific question that provides specific context with specific examples and presumably a specific answer.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you for the comment, it's confusing to me why parts of speech are smaller than grammar because grammer is `words, clauses, phrases` and parts of speech are `nouns, verbs, adjectives,...` and so it seems like the words, phrases, and clauses are the things building the parts of speech which seems to go counter to the brick house analogy.

Comment: Nowadays, people do not analyze the English language in isolation. The study of grammar is in modern times part of the field of linguistics; specifically, it relates to the sub-fields of syntax and morphology. General theories of syntax (that aim to be applicable to Language in general, not just English) are the basis of modern definitions of parts of speech, phrases, and grammatical relations. The concept of "phoneme" relates to the linguistic sub-field of phonology, which builds on phonetics.

Comment: `>General theories of syntax are the basis of modern definitions of parts of speech, phrases, and grammatical relations` The question is: how are these modern terms _related_? For example: `General theories of taste are the basis of modern definitions of bread, peanut butter, and jelly. They can be related. Peanut butter goes on top of toast. Jelly can also go on top of toast. Jelly and Peanut butter taste better when placed together and can both be placed on top of toast` Do you see the difference between describing "hey these terms exist" and "hey this is how these terms are _related_"?

Comment: If you're building a house you get some pieces of lumber (the words) and nail them together (using more words) to make walls (phrases) which eventually go together as complete buildings (sentences).

Comment: @mbigras: The relationship will depend on the linguistic theory you are dealing with. As far as I know, there isn't absolute consensus about what parts of speech are. E.g. according to the (non-mainstream) theory of [Distributed Morphology](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~rnoyer/dm/#noun%20and%20verb) " the traditional terms for sentence elements, such as *noun, verb, adjective* have no universal significance and are essentially derivative from more basic morpheme types"; I believe there are alternative viewpoints in other linguistic traditions, so I don't see how a general answer is possible.

Comment: You can see a handout describing a more mainstream view of syntactic categories here: https://msu.edu/course/lin/434/PSets/syntactic-categories.pdf

Comment: I think the question identified by Araucaria seems of reasonable scope but I notice that it doesn't mention phonemes. Would you be OK with editing out the reference to phonemes in the earlier part of your answer? I think that would make the question more focused; phonemes don't really have much to do with any of the other things this question is about. You can always ask a separate question about phonemes (probably it would be best to first read [What, precisely, is a phoneme?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/15753) on the Linguistics Stack Exchange site).

Comment: @sumelic please see edit. Also thank you for the [link](https://msu.edu/course/lin/434/PSets/syntactic-categories.pdf). It seems to clearly highlight the problem I'm having: `"One of the fundamental problems with the way traditional parts of speech are defined is
that they are often a mixture of semantic and syntactic features, and the definitions are not
usually explicit enough to be useful."`

Comment: @HotLicks how do terms like `Noun, Verb, Adjective, Subject, Object, Clause` fit into your analogy?

Comment: I suggest you familiarize yourself with *Context Free Phrase Structure Grammar*, a theory whose linguistic side was invented by Chomsky in the 50s.  It is a basis for several syntactic theories, including TG and GPSG.  In CFPSG, the "non-terminal symbols" are the parts of speech.  Succinctly, you won't know what the parts of speech are until you know at least a part of the syntactic theory under discussion.

Comment: @mbigras - Understand that it's an analogy, and perfect analogies, if possible at all, are exceedingly rare.  But a "part of speech" is any of the various things that is delivered from the building supply company to the house-building site:  Bricks & lumber (nouns), nails (prepositions), paint (adjectives), etc.  I can sorta make an analogy between mortar and verbs, but it's admittedly weak.  The carpenters and other workers assemble these pieces into more and more complex assemblies (phrases of various types) according to a set of plans and specifications (the syntactic rules and semantics).